# Techniques for populating large databases when testing

Tags: database, testing

We are running 3 Oracle databases with 100+ tables in each. In order to test our code we are looking into alternatives for populating them with testdata. The tools we have found this far are DBSetup and DBUnit.

The problem we are having with these tools are all the manual work needed to specify data. For example if I am to test a table D I am required to populate tables A, B, C with data also. I dont care what the data is, i only care about the data in table D. The reason I have to also populate A B C is because the concistency checks on the derived keys in table D.

My questions is how is this type of problem uasually handled? Is this a sign of a badly designed database from a testability point of view?

Answer (score 0):

If the database is strictly for testing purposes, I don't see anything stopping you from dropping the consistency checks (FK etc), populate the data, test it, truncate the table, and readd the consistency checks again later.
Other alternative that I can think of 
1. copy the table structure (columns etc), and do your testing there
2. alter all FKs with "deferrable initially deferred" that basically will postpone the consistency checking until you commit the transaction

Comment: Well I would like to test the consistensychecks also I guess.

Comment: If you want to check the data consistency with other table then you definitely need to populate reference table's data. Otherwise, how you're going to know if the data is consistent or not :)

Answer (score 0):

we stopped using dbunit and started to populate the db programmaticaly. this way you can create one factory method that creates your entity with all its dependencies. and then you can this one method as many times as possible.

i would avoid removing constraints during the process of testing. if the code you test create/modifies the data, you may get false positive results without constraints. same with performance

if you have to populate 100 tables just to insert anything to table X then yes, i would say there might be some problem with design. think if you can better divide your domain into smaller aggregate roots. but if you need just a few other tables then i would say there is nothing wrong with it